# Specifying an explicit type for maven deploy

Tags: java, maven, deployment, nexus, izpack

I am using the [IzPack-maven-plugin](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/IZPACK/IzPack+Maven+Plugin+Reference) with its own "izpack-jar" packaging type to create an installer artifact. The plugin creates this artifact locally as a `.jar` file, but deploys it as type `izpack-jar`. Therefore it will get an `.izpack-jar` extension when fetching that artifact from nexus.

In [code](https://github.com/izpack/izpack/blob/master/izpack-maven-plugin/src/main/java/org/izpack/mojo/IzPackNewMojo.java#L205) of the plugin contains the following lines:

```
project.getArtifact().setFile(jarFile);
[...]
file = new File(outputDirectory, finalName + localClassifier + ".jar");
```

The second one creates the file explicitly as a `.jar` file and the first one simply sets this file as the main artifact.

Is it generally possible to build an artifact with one packaging type but deploy it with another type?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the extension for the type `izpack-jar` is defined as `jar`, so it should be deployed as jar-file (while still the packaging type is izpack.jar).

## Update:

see sourcecode (https://github.com/izpack/izpack/blob/master/izpack-maven-plugin/src/main/resources/META-INF/plexus/components.xml):

```
<component>
  <role>org.apache.maven.artifact.handler.ArtifactHandler</role>
  <role-hint>izpack</role-hint>
  <implementation>org.apache.maven.artifact.handler.DefaultArtifactHandler</implementation>
  <configuration>
    <type>izpack</type>
    <includesDependencies>false</includesDependencies>
    <language>java</language>
    <extension>jar</extension>
    <addedToClasspath>true</addedToClasspath>
    <packaging>izpack-jar</packaging>
  </configuration>
</component>
```

Packaging and extension can be different (for example in case of bundles or maven-plugins).

You could deploy with a different type by explicitly masking the the the `default-deploy` execution (binding it to a non-existant lifecycle phase) and binding `deploy:deploy-file` to your lifecycle, however I would not recommend it.

Comment: Where is the extension defined as jar? (I only see the local file defined as .jar) Nexus definitely list the deployed artifact as <type>izpack-jar</type> and dependency:copy also creates a .izpack-jar file.

Comment: I will update my answer. You can download the artifact either using the extension _or_ the type, i.e. if you declare your dependency as type jar, it will still work (look inside the nexus repo using a browser, it should show a jar file, not a izpack jar)

Comment: In my nexus for that artifact the right column "download" lists "pom" and "izpack-jar". Downloading as "jar" fails. - That's why I started to wonder.

Comment: Also `mvn dependency:copy -Dartifact=group:artifact:version:jar` fails and `mvn dependency:copy -Dartifact=group:artifact:version:izpack-jar` succeeds.

Comment: What is the difference between `<role-hint>`, `type`, and `<packaging>` in the component above? Seems like changing the `<role-hint>` to "izpack-jar" [fixed](https://github.com/rkrell/izpack/commit/13a5f7f7a7961ce3103ecb7f97be5cdf5ea215a9) the issue.